Identifying Movie/TV Show with two sisters
I was very young when my parents watched a show from the late 80s early 90s. All I can remember:

Two women lived in the same house (they might be sisters)
One is in a wheel chair and had very short, blonde hair
Women are probably in their early 50s
The one in the wheel chair thinks the other is trying to kill her
She thinks this because she falls out of the chair in their stair-elevator, and finds worms in her sandwich
These things that are happening might not be real and is in her head
I think the other woman must be her caretaker


Could be What Ever Happened to Baby Jane?

An elderly, bedridden former movie star is "cared for" by her sister, who hates her and keeps her a virtual prisoner in the family mansion.

Some similarities from here


Blanche's career was cut short by a car accident that paralyzed her from the waist down
Jane resents both her sister's enduring popularity and her own role as caretaker
...takes out her resentment on Blanche with vicious, childlike pranks, such as putting worms in Blanche's food or cutting off all Blanche's hair.



Wow, that looks pretty weird. Not my cup of tea after all, but that is definitely it. Well done!

glad I could help!
